# Is there any way to run a workflow on site creation?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

In our SharePoint online environment we have an app that provisions new sites. My problem is that this app is developed by an external company and it is not easy to get access to the code (due to internal policies).

I need to run a site workflow that starts on a site just after creation. Is that possible in any way without user actions?

The site is created using a site template, which is deployed as a solution through Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, you can initiate workflow right after the site collection creation, because workflow needs to read from some where to perform the activity.

So you have couple of options:

- create a an event receiver which will trigger when a new site collection created.[check this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/02/event-receivers-in-sharepoint/)

Another Method:

- create a list with required information i.e. site collection name, Site admins, url etc.
- Now configure a workflow on that list which run after every x time and check if site collection is created then send the notification.

another example is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2007/03/03/how-to-create-a-site-collection-in-a-workflow.aspx